# sed remove multiple characters surrounded by digits

Tags: sed, character

I have a file with following contents:

```
EMAIL|TESTNUMBER|DATE

somemail@address.com|123456789|2011-02-08T16:36:02Z
```

How do I remove capital letters `T` between the date and time and `Z` at the end of the line using `sed`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If the format is fixed and each line always matches T\d\d:\d\d:\d\dZ, then you could try the simple:

```
$ sed 's/T\(..:..:..\)Z$/ \1/'
```

(Untested)

Answer (score 0):

Cat it through:

```
sed 's/\([0-9]+\)T\([0-9]+\)/\1\2//' | sed 's/Z$//'
```

---

**Edit**
Oh my! I've just realized (thanks @Fredrik) that for a long time I wasted processes! Shame on me! Now I'm Church of The One Process convert. Here is the blessed version of the above abominated oneliner:

```
sed 's/\([0-9]+\)T\([0-9]+\)/\1\2//; s/Z$//'  the_file.txt
```

Comment: There's no need for the pipe.  You can always do: sed -e cmd1 -e cmd2 which is equivalent to sed cmd1 | sed cmd2

Comment: @William Pursell: Cool :) I'll take it into account next time.

Comment: please do, else people will start to throw this at you http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps there's a fancier way, but the following script works for me:

```
s/\(....-..-..\)T\(.*\)/\1 \2/

s/Z$//
```

Example...in-bound file:

```
somemail@address.com|123456789|2011-02-08A16:36:02X
somemail@address.com|123456789|2011-02-08T16:36:02Z
somemail@address.com|123456789|2011-02-08B16:36:02Y
```

Output:

```
D:\>sed -f sedscr testfile

somemail@address.com|123456789|2011-02-08A16:36:02X
somemail@address.com|123456789|2011-02-08 16:36:02
somemail@address.com|123456789|2011-02-08B16:36:02Y
```